# git status -> Show files that will be added (staged) in subdirectories

Tags: git, version-control

Say I start a git repository in a folder, and I have several subdirectories in it.

I have several globbing patterns `.gitignore` to exclude files in the subdirectories. However, when I do `git status` **before I stage anything**, git status only shows the names of the subfolders that will be added, without being specific about which files in each subdirectory will be added (staged) if I do `git add .`.

Interestingly though, `git status` is explicit about the files that will be **committed** after I stage files with `git add .`.

Is there anyway to ask `git status` to be explicit about files for the files that would be **staged**?

Answer (score 221):

Try:

```
git status -u
```

or the long form:

```
git status --untracked-files
```

which will show individual files in untracked directories.

Here's the detailed description of `-u` option from [git-status man page](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-status.html):

> `-u[<mode>]`
> `--untracked-files[=<mode>]`
>
> Show untracked files.
>
> The mode parameter is optional (defaults to `all`), and is used to specify the handling of untracked files; when `-u` is not used, the default is `normal`, i.e. show untracked files and directories.
>
> The possible options are:
>
> - `no` - Show no untracked files
> - `normal` - Shows untracked files and directories
> - `all` - Also shows individual files in untracked directories.
>
> The default can be changed using the `status.showUntrackedFiles` configuration variable documented in [git-config(1)](http://schacon.github.io/git/git-config.html).

Answer (score 18):

You can simply use

```
git add --dry-run .
```

in the root of your repository which gives you a list of any file in any sub directory that would be added while considering `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 7):

> [`git ls-files -o --exclude-standard`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-ls-files.html)

Every path in your worktree that isn't staged (`-o`) and won't be ignored by `git add` (`--exclude-standard`).

Answer (score 0):

How about putting a `.gitignore` file in your sub directories instead along the line of

```
# Ignore everything in this directory
*
# Except these file
!.gitignore
!file1
!file2
!file3
```

Comment: I don't have anything in my `.gitignore` that looks like what you posted (i.e. ignoring directories or subdirectories with exceptions).  Also, why would that matter? By the way, `git status` returns the list of files that would be committed correctly *after staging* with `git add .`.

Comment: I know you do not. Remove the directory from the root `.gitignore` and add this `.gitignore` in your sub directory - you can have more than one. They nest

Answer (score -1):

use git command 
git ls-files -o 
 to list untracked file

instead -o use 
-c
--cached
Show cached files in the output (default)

-d
--deleted
Show deleted files in the output

-m
--modified
Show modified files in the output

Comment: This question is specific to showing what files will be added, while accounting for .gitignore. Your answer ignores .gitignore.

Answer (score -1):

There is a huge chance it is due to line ending. Solution:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

But don't just run this command, validate before executing it. Use `git diff`, if most of the files show no difference, it is due to line ending. Use it well.